# How can core.autocrlf be still set if it is not set in local/global/system level?

Tags: git, git-config, gitattributes

On windows (`git version 2.14.1.windows.1`) all the following do not print 
 anything:

```
git config --global core.autocrlf
git config --system core.autocrlf
git config --local core.autocrlf
```

but the following prints `true`

```
git config core.autocrlf
```

How can this be possible? Where is this value stored?

Comment: Check `$HOME/.config/git/config`. See https://www.git-scm.com/docs/git-config#FILES.

Comment: @ElpieKay I don't have such a file, but I have `%HOME%/.gitconfig` that contains it.

Comment: If so, it should have been printed by `global`. I don’t know why then.

Comment: @ElpieKay My bad. Yes I had set it as --global at the time that I checked. Now I have unset it, however as said in the question `git config core.autocrlf` still shows true. So, since I cannot find `$HOME/.config/git/config` where else could it be?

Comment: It seems you've found it. Could you please tell where it is?

Comment: @ElpieKay Output of `git config --show-origin core.autocrlf` : `file:"C:\\ProgramData/Git/config" true`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your Git version is at least 2.8.0, run:

```
git config --show-origin core.autocrlf
```

For instance, with my configuration—where `core.autocrlf` is not set so I must use another name—I get:

```
$ git config --show-origin alias.outgoing
file:<path>/.gitconfig  log --oneline @{u}..
```

(`git outgoing` is a quick way to look at what commits I have that `git push` is likely to push).